# Android camera, seconds rounded to integers on geotag

Tags: java, android, gps, android-camera, exif

I am attempting to geotag my photos in a custom camera app. Here is my onLocationChanged() Method:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mGpsLocation.locationChanged(location.getLatitude(),
            location.getLongitude(), location.getAltitude());
    mGpsLocation.update();

    mLat = String.valueOf(mGpsLocation.getLat());
    mLon = String.valueOf(mGpsLocation.getLon());
    mAlt = String.valueOf(mGpsLocation.getAlt());

    paramView.setText("Lat: " + mLat + "\n" + "Lon: " + mLon + "\n"
            + "Alt: " + mAlt);

     Camera.Parameters gpsParams = mCamera.getParameters();
     gpsParams.set("gps-altitude", mAlt);
     gpsParams.set("gps-latitude", mLat);
     gpsParams.set("gps-longitude", mLon);
     mCamera.setParameters(gpsParams);
}
```

mGpsLocation is an instance of a custom class I created. I know it works, because displaying my location via paramView.setText() gives me accurate values with up to 14 decimal places. However, when I view the photos on my PC with GeoSetter, the location data looks like Nxx*xx'47.00" and Wxx*xx'89.00" (xx is a legitimate value). This results in a low res grid when I view the photos over satellite imagery.

I also tried saving the data directly to the Exif header, but this results in no gps data whatsoever.

```
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE, dirName);
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            Log.d("",
                    "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");
            return;
        }

          try{ 
              ExifInterface exif = new    ExifInterface(pictureFile.getName());
              exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, mLat);
              exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, mLon);
              exif.saveAttributes(); 
          } catch(IOException e){
              e.printStackTrace(); 
          }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get higher resolution data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a problem. I needed to write the Exif data *after* the file is has been written. Should have noticed that earlier. Since the Exif header takes rational values for degrees, minutes, and seconds; I now have no problems with truncating/rounding.

I'm still curious, however, as to why setting gps location via Camera.Parameters didn't work correctly. Could it have something to do with the fact that I was passing decimal values? Using the same fractional values I now set directly to the Exif header doesn't work at all.

Regardless, writing to the Exif header directly is, I think, the best solution.